# How to port tables with data, stored procs, functions from local server to remote?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the best method to port sql server 2008 tables with data as well as functions, stored procs from one server to another?  Just to be clear this is for an existing (large) database. I just have 10-12 tables to move over with the stored procs & functions.

Answer (score 3):

[Backup and restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx) the database.

Comment: It's somewhat of a partial update to an existing (large) database.  I just have 10-12 tables to move over with the stored procs & functions.